# How to locate the thrift installation directory in ubuntu14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thrift

I need to go to the directory lib/py on the thrift installation directory, but I cannot find it after installation (using sudo apt-get install thrift-compiler)

Comment: how did you install thrift?

Comment: [the list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/thrift-compiler/filelist) for this package does not contain the folder you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler and the libraries needed for each language are not the same. You installed the `thrift-compiler` package only, which - as the name suggests - does only contain the Thrift compiler binaries. I don't have an Ubuntu at hand right now, but there are basically three solutions:

- find the libraries package matching the compiler version [in the Ubuntu repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-thrift)
- download the files from the [Thrift download page](http://thrift.apache.org/download) or the [Thrift download archive](http://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/)
- `git checkout` the branch from the [repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git)